# Once I’m at the office

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Is the below sentence correct?

> I will confirm once I’m at the office.

I’m trying to tell someone that I will confirm later because I’m not at the office meanwhile.  I could not digest “once” followed by “I’m”. That is why I was confused.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct and completely natural expression.   However, could you edit your question to add more detail what you find difficult or confusing about this grammar?  Otherwise the question may be closed.

Comment: Could also be "I will confirm once I’m ***in*** the office."

Comment: @Andrew I could not digest “once” followed by “I’m”. That is why I was confused.

Comment: regarding @WeatherVane's comment, the choice of **at** or **in** would depend on whether you regarded **office** as simply a room  (where **in** would be appropriate), or as business premises, where **at** would be appropriate).

Comment: @JavaLatte I work in an open space office so I think “at” would be the write choice. Correct me If I was wrong.

Comment: @shayqi, a private office would more likely be **in**, because we think of it more as a room than as business premises. For an open plan office, both **at** or **in** are acceptable, but **at** is certainly more likely unless you want to make it clear that you are actually inside a particular room.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, **once** is acting as a conjunction, which is used to connect two clauses to make a sentence. The two clauses are

> I will confirm 
>   I’m at the office.

The two clauses are grammatically correct, and **once** adds the meaing that the first clause will take place **as soon as** the second clause occurs.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/once), **once** can be an adverb or a conjunction. The adverbal usage is more common and has a different meaning: maybe that's what is making you uncomfortable about the sentence. You could replace **once** with the conjunction **[when](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/when)**, and the meaning would be almost the same, but without the sense of urgency.

> I will confirm **when** I’m at the office.